# Error: Unknown column in field list

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, field

While running the below script it shows the errorError: Unknown column 'email' in 'field list'.

```
  <?php
  include("connect.php");

  if($loggedin == '1')
  die("You can't register another account while you're logged in.");

  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {

  $uname = trim($_POST['username']);

 if($_POST["regkey"]!="171717")
 die("Invalid Registration Key. <br> <a href= register.php>Back</a>");

 if($_POST["pass"]!=$_POST["pass2"])
 die("Passwords do not match. <br> <a href= register.php>Back</a>");

 // Make sure all forms were filled out.

 if((!isset($_POST['username'])) || (!isset($_POST['pass']))
 || ($uname == '') || ($_POST['pass'] == ''))
 die("Please fill out the form completely. <br><br>
 <a href=register.php>Continue</a>");


 $check = @mysql_query("SELECT id FROM players WHERE username = '$uname'");
 $check = @mysql_num_rows($check);

 if($check > 0)
 die("Sorry, that username has already been taken. Please try again.
 <br><br>
 <a href=register.php>Continue</a>");


 $pass = md5($_POST['pass']);

 $date = date("m/d/y");


 $newPlayer = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO players (username, password,   

registered,callname,email) VALUES   ('$uname','$pass','$date','$_POST

[callname]','$_POST[email]')") or die("Error: ".mysql_error());

echo 'You have been registered! You may now <a href=index.php>Log in</a>.';


}
else
{

// A simple example of a form.

echo '
<center>
<form action=register.php method=post>
<p>Registration is currently<b> NOT OPEN.</b><br>
 You must have a valid Registration key to register.</p>
 <table border="2">
 <tr>
<td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="username" size="20px"</input>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Callname:</td><td><input type="text" name="callname" size="20px"</input>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="pass" size="20px"</input>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Re-type Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="pass2" size="20px"</input>  
</td>  </tr>
<tr>
<td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="email" size="20px"</input></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Registration Key:</td><td><input type="text" name="regkey" size="20px"></input>                                                                                         

 </td>    </tr>
 </table>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></input>
 </form>';

 }


 ?>
```

I'm very new to PHP and can't figure out why I'm getting this Error. Shouldn't the $_POST get that value from the form?
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means your `players` table does not contain an `email` column. You will need to add this column to your table for this script to work.

So the incorrect part in your code is

```
$newPlayer = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO players(username, password, registered, callname, email)
                           VALUES('$uname', '$pass', '$date', '$_POST[callname]', '$_POST[email]')") or die("Error: ".mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem.

Comment: Good to hear. Please consider upvoting my answer and accepting my answer (by clicking the green checkbox beside my answer)

Comment: In my case, the column did exist but I forgot to enclose the non-integer variable in quotes! ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add an `email` field in your player table.
2. Chances are there you misspelled `email` in the player.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_registration (u_name,s_father,s_schoolname,s_rollno,s_class)
VALUES ($name,$father,$school,$rollno,$class)";
```

> Error: INSERT INTO user_registration
>   (u_name,s_father,s_schoolname,s_rollno,s_class) VALUES (Azhar, hassan,
>   Chulli_payaan,1008,10th) Unknown column 'Azhar' in 'field list'

Comment: please any one tell me the above error. unknown column

Comment: I am new with php. I am in trouble please anyone help me